# JScrollPane doesn't belong to JTable

Tags: java, swing

I added a JScrollPane for my JTable. It showed up, but not scrollable.

```
public class AddDepartment extends JFrame {
    private static JPanel contentPane;
    private Connection DBConnection;
    static Connection conn = new DBConnection().connect();
    static PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
    static ResultSet rs = null;
    static DefaultTableModel model = null;
    private static JTable tableDepartments;
    private static JScrollPane scrollPane;

    public AddDepartment() throws SQLException {
        model = new DefaultTableModel();
        tableDepartments = new JTable(model);
        tableDepartments.setRowSelectionAllowed(false);
        tableDepartments.setEnabled(false);
        tableDepartments.setSize(new Dimension(197, 66));
        tableDepartments.setLocation(161, 34);
        tableDepartments.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);

        updateDepartments();
    }

    private static void updateDepartments() throws SQLException {
        try {
            String sql = "SELECT Name FROM Departments";
            pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            rs = pstmt.executeQuery();

            model.addColumn("Name");
            while (rs.next()) {
                String departmentName = rs.getString("Name");
                model.addRow(new Object[] { departmentName });
            }
            if (tableDepartments.getRowCount() > 5) {
                scrollPane = new JScrollPane(tableDepartments);
                scrollPane.setSize(new Dimension(10, 50));
                scrollPane.setLocation(360, 34);
                scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
                contentPane.add(scrollPane);
            }
            contentPane.add(tableDepartments);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
        } finally {
            rs.close();
            pstmt.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Departments table:

[image: Departments table]

[image: This is how it looks like]

Above picture shows how it looks like. I cannot scrolldown.

Comment: (1-) This is NOT a SSCCE. How many times do you have to be told we can't execute this code because we don't have access to your database!!! Your question is about scrolling which has absolutely nothing to do with getting data from a database. You have been told several times to post your SSCCE with hardcoded data so we can execute your code to see exactly what is happening. If you want help make an effort instead of asking 4 questions on the same topic. With a proper SSCCE this would have been solved with the first question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By constraining your JTable size:

```
tableDepartments.setSize(new Dimension(197, 66));
```

you prevent it from sizing as needed and thus prevent it from scrolling. Don't do this, but instead let it expand to its desired size. If this doesn't fix your problem, then you will need to create and post a valid [sscce](http://sscce.org), a program that has no database code, no code not relevant to the problem and that demonstrates your problem for us.

Other issues include a gross over-use of the static modifier, and your setting absolute sizes and positions (and likely use of null layouts) but that's for another question

---

**Edit**
You're adding your JTable **twice** to the GUI, once to the JScrollPane (good) and again to the contentPane (bad), and this is messing you up since you can only add a component to **one** container. The 2nd add is removing the jtable from the jscrollpane. Solution: don't do this. Add the jscrollpane to the contentPane, **not** the JTable.

So get rid of:

```
contentPane.add(tableDepartments);
```

Comment: But if l remove the line you wrote, table disappears. Can you also explain what you wanted to say in your last paragraph?

Comment: @Munchmallow: then create and post a [mcve] a [sscce](http://sscce.org). Please check the links. Re the last statements, if you use null layouts, and set component's sizes, you create rigid gui's that are next to impossible to debug or enhance. Over use of static increases code connectivity and thus the risks of bugs.

Comment: @Munchmallow: shit, you're adding the JTable **Twice** to the GUI, once to the jscrollpane (good) and then again to the contentpane (bad). Don't do that!

Comment: @Munchmallow: what??

Comment: I deleted my last comment.
So for the recap, When I use JScrollPane with JTable, I only have to add JScrollPane to the contentPane `contentPane.add(scrollPane);`, right?

Comment: @Munchmallow: bottom line is that you can add a component to only one container. You're adding the JTable to the JScrollPane's viewport and thus can add it to nothing else. You then add the JScrollPane to another container that is ultimately displayed by the top-level window, here the JFrame. Next learn about the layout managers, use them, and avoid using null layouts and setting sizes and locations.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Do you have a link for that?

Comment: @Munchmallow, this is the third person who has asked you to post a SSCCE/MCVE. Next time I will close your question as a duplicate if a proper SSCCE is not included with your question. Regarding layouts, read the  [Swing tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html)  for Swing basics. There are section on `Using Layout Managers`, `How to Use Tables`, `How to Use Lists` which all contain working examples and will show you how to better structure your code . The code doesn't execute on the Event Dispatch Thread. You should NOT be using static variables. Don't extend JFrame.

Comment: Eclipse suggests to use static because it shows some errors.

Comment: @Munchmallow: no, it's saying you can't use something in a static context. The solution is not to make things static, but rather not to use it in a static context. You need to learn about what an object is and how to use them before moving forward as this is key to all Java programming, not just Swing.

Comment: But I am using them inside two different functions. Instead of calling the class each time in different classes, I thought it would be okay if I make it global. With this thought, eclipse suggests me to make the method static.
E.g: I am using db connection(`static Connection conn = new DBConnection().connect();`)  in both `updateDepartments`and button click action,I also have a button which I didn't show the code because it is not related to JTable, Should I still call `Connection conn = new DBConnection().connect();` in each function that I am using the db connection?

Comment: @Munchmallow: this question is not related to the main question posted, that of the JTable not showing. But bottom line is no, it is not OK to make it global. You need to learn how to use OOPs to its fullest. In a real application, the database code would be in a completely separate class from the GUI code.